# Empty Angular2 project increases memory in IE 11

Tags: angular, memory, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-11

My company is currently building a very large SPA written in Angular 2 and we have some issues regarding memory consumption.

During my tests, I have commented out all code from the app, leaving just the main module and two components that are completely empty.
We use Webpack for transpilation purposes.

While profiling in Chrome, the memory consumption seemed quite consistent, but when I did the same in IE11 (the client will mainly use this browser), the memory seems to constantly increase even if I refresh the browser window.

Following are two screenshots of the IE profiler as well as the task manager. Each spike indicates a browser refresh.
Also note, that taking a heap snapshot is showing a constant value of 3.16Mb for my website, so nothing wrong there.

This issue is made worse on the full version, where after some hours of work, the browser can reach over 1Gb.

[image: IE 11 memory profiler]

The Task Manager :

[image: Task Manager]

Is this constant memory increase in IE11 a known issue?
If you would like some more info on my implementation please ask.

Comment: hmmm these issues could be related : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8112 , https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16329 , I didn't find your specific issue though, maybe worth a bug report ?

Comment: the issue talking about bad performance suggests to use core-js instead of es6-shim, have you tried that ? also are you by any chance running IE 11 in compatibility mode because that's not supported ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total memory increasing in IE with Angular Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399136/total-memory-increasing-in-ie-with-angular-directive)